# how to mock a module that takes a parameter

Tags: node.js, jestjs, pg-promise

I am trying to write a unit test for code that uses pg-promise, it looks like this:

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

const cn = {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
};

function insertStuff(stuff) {
  let db = pgp(cn);
  return db.one('INSERT INTO test(stuff) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id, stuff', [stuff])
    .then(data => {
      return data
    })
 }
 module.exports.insertStuff = insertStuff
```

The test code looks like this:

```
const mockFakeDb = {
  one: jest.fn()
}

jest.mock("pg-promise", () => {
  return mockFakeDb
})

 const insertStuff = require("../src/db-utils").insertStuff

 test("params for inserting stuff are correct", done => {
   mockFakeDb.one.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({id: 123456789, stuff: "stuff"})

   insertStuff("stuff").then((data) => {
   const insertCall = fakeDb.one.mock.calls[0]
   expect(insertCall).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
   done()
 })
})
```

so in trying to mock pg-promise require I get an error:
TypeError: require(...) is not a function.
I can see that pg-promise has a function which takes parameters (the second brackets) but not sure how to now mock this?

Comment: It is not clear where `TypeError: require(...) ` is coming from. Also, if you are mocking the protocol, you should use `noLocking` from [Intialization Options](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.  I've kind of gotten past that now. however I am now getting the error that pgp is not a function.

Comment: how can I mock the protocol?  It would be better if it could just do its thing and then mock the db

Comment: What's stopping you from mocking the db in the standard way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'standard way'.  the way I would usually do this is to mock the module and then replace the functions I call with jest.fn() implementations (as above).  Do you have an example of mocking db?  I've checked out your wiki but can't see anything there

Comment: The standard way - you mock up individual methods that you are trying to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else not quite sure how to do this:

```
const fakeDB = {
  one: jest.fn()
}

function fakePgpFunc() {
  return fakeDB
}
fakePgpFunc.end = jest.fn()

jest.doMock("pg-promise", () => {
  return jest.fn(() => fakePgpFunc)
})

const insertStuff = require("../src/db-utils").insertStuff

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks()
})

test("params for inserting stuff are correct", done => {
  fakeDB.one.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({"stuff": "Stuff", "id": 123456789})
  })

  insertStuff("Stuff").then((data) => {
    expect(fakeDB.one).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    const insertStuffCall = fakeDB.one.mock.calls[0]
    expect(insertStuffCall[0]).toEqual("INSERT INTO test(stuff) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id, stuff")
    expect(queryInsertCall[1]).toEqual(["Stuff"])
    expect(data).toEqual({id: 123456789, stuff: "Stuff"})
    expect(fakePgpFunc.end).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    done()
  })
})
```